# Is it possible to move a part with repect to constraints in Product using Catia vba?

Tags: vba, catia

I have to move a probe like sphere between two parts such that the probe is in contact with both the parts. And I have to find the point of contact of the parts, measure their distance and make a fillet on the parts based on this distance. I have achieved in moving the sphere between the parts but the sphere is moving through the parts. So trying to move with respect to constraints

I am trying to automate the manipulate tool in Catia Product.
Is there any command or method exist to move a part with respect to contraints  in Catia using vba ?

Or

Is there any way to find the clash between two parts using vba ?

Looking Forward for a solution.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You can move parts with the API via a manipulation/position matrix, but not necessarily with respect to constraints(I will have to dig deeper). I haven't tried clash, but I suspect it's not exposed in VBA API(only CAA) What exactly is the purpose of your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.eng-tips.com/search.cfm?pid=560&action=Search&q=clash&t=&h=&searchSite=1&searchArea=1&d=1&s=1) is a link where you can find a solution for clash.

OK, I got the idea, you want to see the code here :-)

To compute clash in a CATScript:

```
    Sub CATMain()

    ' get root product of document
    Dim RootProd As Product
    Set RootProd = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Product

    ' retrieve selection object of active document
    Dim objSelection As Selection
    Set objSelection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection

    ' get two selected objects
    If (objSelection.Count2 <> 2) Then
    MsgBox "Before running the script you must select two products to compute clash for", vbOKOnly, "No products selected"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim FirstProd As Product
    Dim SecondProd As Product

    Set FirstProd = objSelection.Item2(1).Value
    Set SecondProd = objSelection.Item2(2).Value

    ' create groups for clash computation
    Dim objGroups As Groups
    Set objGroups = RootProd.GetTechnologicalObject("Groups")

    Dim grpFirst As Group
    Dim grpSecond As Group

    Set grpFirst = objGroups.Add()
    Set grpSecond = objGroups.Add()

    ' add selected products to groups
    grpFirst.AddExplicit FirstProd
    grpSecond.AddExplicit SecondProd


    ' get access to Clashes collection
    Dim objClashes As Clashes
    Set objClashes = RootProd.GetTechnologicalObject("Clashes")

    ' create new clash
    Dim newClash As Clash
    Set newClash = objClashes.Add()

    ' set new clash to be computed between two groups (two selected products)
    newClash.FirstGroup = grpFirst
    newClash.SecondGroup = grpSecond

    newClash.ComputationType = catClashComputationTypeBetweenTwo

    ' compute clash
    newClash.Compute

    End Sub
```